# JSON to HTML Table conversion

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I want to display the JSON data I get from server to my HTML page in a Tabular form. I have created a js function to do this:

```
function saveImage(){

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          // Optionally, here you can update the dom to have a table in "responseDiv"
       //  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<pre>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</pre>";
            var items= document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
          var test = items.xmlhttp.responseText

          $table = "<table id = 'resultTable'><td>Digits</td><td>Probability</td><tr>";

            for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

                $table += "<tr>";

                var it = test[i];

                $table += "<td>" + test[i].Digits + "</td>";

                $table += "<td>" + test[i].Probability + "</td>";


                 //alert(items[i].duration);
                $table += "</tr>";

            }

            $table += "</table>";

            $('myDiv').append($table);
            $table = "<table id = 'resultTable'><td>Digits</td><td>Probability</td><tr>";
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "analyzeImage", true);
  // Convert the canvas data to a data-uri encoded PNG image
  var dataURIPostBody = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//  window.open(dataURIPostBody, '_blank', 'location=0, menubar=0');
  xmlhttp.send(dataURIPostBody);
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="myDiv">
    <h4>Confusion Matrix</h4>
    <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 250px;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

But nothing is getting displayed on to my HTML page. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `<tr>` tag is opened outside the `for` loop and inside the `for` loop, and closed only once, which is wrong. Have look

Answer (score 0):

your xmlhttp.responseText is still in text format, you need to parse it into json objects by using a JSON package such as json2.js, so get json2.js and reference it in you html code then you can call JSON.parse(xmlhttp.respoonseText) to convert your responsetext to a json array.  I also changed the way you construct the table, I have not tested your code, but I use this in multiple place and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        try
        {
           var test = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

           var table      = $("#resultTable").get(0);
          var row = table.insertRow();
          var cell1 = row.insertCell();
          var cell2 = row.insertCell();
          cell1.innerHTML = "Digits";
          cell2.innerHTML = "Probability";

            for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

                row = table.insertRow();
                cell1 = row.insertCell();
                cell2 = row.insertCell();
                cell1.innerHTML = test[i].Digits;
                cell2.innerHTML = test[i].Probability;
            }
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
          alert(ex.message+": Error parsing server response, "+xmlhttp.responseText);
        }

      }
  }
```

Add a table to your html code in the div section so you can reference it in your js code when building the content of table,

```
<div class="col-md-3" id="myDiv">
        <h4>Confusion Matrix</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 250px;">
         <table id='resultTable'>
         </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi @falijbour, I tried this code, but its unable to get the results. It just display the headings: Digits Probability.

Comment: I based my answer assuming that the responseText contains an array of json objects, that tells me that test is not an array,  print out your xmlhttp.responseText or show what is suppose to show up from the server

Comment: added a try catch statement to see if the JSON.parse is throwing an exception due to improper json objects

Comment: I am getting error parsing server response: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of undefined: Error parsing server response, {
  "1": 0.99, 
  "2": 0.8, 
  "3": 0.6
}

Comment: what does the alert box contain beside "Error parsing server response", it should have the content of the text sent by the server.  Do you know what is expected to be sent by the server. If so, please add it to your question

Comment: Yes, the alert box displays: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of undefined: Error parsing server response, { "1": 0.99, "2": 0.8, "3": 0.6 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75621/discussion-between-faljbour-and-katie).

Comment: @Katie, You may want to mark the solution if it is working for you so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Its not working now. I ll update if it does. Thanks.